# Drop items to empty Detailslist

Tags: office-ui-fabric

I have two detailslist and I want to drag items from one to another, the problem is the second DetailsList is empty when component initialized and it doesn't accept drag and drop operations, but as soon as I add an item to the list it start getting  dropped items.

Comment: By chance, does drag & drop work if you push a `null` item onto the list? You can control how `null` items are rendered using the `onRenderMissingItem` prop, https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/blob/80553ec8d2a7735dc0503d47fa7913b18fa7d2eb/packages/office-ui-fabric-react/src/components/DetailsList/DetailsList.types.ts#L175.

Comment: I tried that, but no luck!

Comment: Simply append or initialize your DetailsList items array with a `null` value and it should invoke `onRenderMissingItem` when rendering the control. However, `onRenderMissingItem` is likely not useful for your specific scenario. I just want to see if you are able to drag and drop with an items array containing a null value.